# Toastr undefined in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, undefined, toastr

I am doing tutorial and this part is about implementing login and this should give baloons about login success

```
angular.module("app").value("mvToastr", toastr);

angular.module("app").factory("mvNotifier", function(mvToastr) {
   return {
      notify: function(msg) {
          mvToastr.success(msg);
          console.log(msg);
       }
    }
});
```

I am getting this and I don't understand it a bit. All .js files seem to be loaded. Please tell me where is the problem, thank you.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
   at getOptions (http://localhost:3030/vendor/toastr/toastr.js:282:14)
   at Object.success (http://localhost:3030/vendor/toastr/toastr.js:68:17)
   at Object.notify (http://localhost:3030/app/common/mvNotifier.js:6:22)
   at http://localhost:3030/app/account/mvNavBarLoginCtrl.js:8:28
   at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:11033:81)
   at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:11033:81)
   at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:11119:26
   at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:12045:28)
   at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:11871:31)
   at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:12151:24)

   angular.js:9503
```

Comment: it's pluralsight premium http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/building-angularjs-nodejs-apps-mean - Improving the Client Login Code

Comment: Congrats, your question helped me implement toastr as an Angular service. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the [toastr sources](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/master/toastr.js) it looks like `getOptions()` calls jQuery's `$.extend()` method.

Toastr takes a dependency on jQuery, from the first line of the github readme:

> toastr is a Javascript library for non-blocking notifications. **jQuery
>   is required**. The goal is to create a simple core library that can be
>   customized and extended.

Just include jquery in your master view html.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you are right. I had jquery and i knew it, but the path was wrong. i had `jquery/jquery.js` but i should have `jquery/dist/jquery.js` @phil

Comment: This makes no difference to me. I pull in jQuery before toastr.js and it still doesn't work. Angular just doesn't like it.

Comment: @ArminderDahul late reply I know, but toastr *does* work fine with angular. You should include jquery *before* angular, otherwise angular will essentially overwrite jquery with its own "jqlite" implementation. https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turns out Toastr needs JQuery to work, always make sure you **include JQuery before Toastr**, for example in `angular.json`:

```
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", // Make sure this comes before
              "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js", // this one
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem working with automated tasks and then loading up in browser.  I upgraded browser-sync and it fixed it.